# Какая нужна программа для работы с java2

Tags: java

В общем читаю книгу Ноутона и Шилдта "java2" Там приводятся много примеров. Так вот что мне нужно, что бы я мог делать все то же самое что написано в книге?
Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо, вот только может подскажете где скачать все это добро можно?

Comment: мы же тебе и так кидаем запросы для гугла ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В самом простом случае достаточно установить Java Development Kit. Потом в блокноте набрать код

```
public class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Скомпилировать

```
javac Hello.java
```

и выполнить

```
java -cp . Hello
```

Если хочется IDE, то их много: NetBeans, Eclipse и т.д.

Comment: такое впечатление что в книжке, которую читает автор вопроса, об этом не рассказывают. Есть подозрение что все это есть в первых главах.

Comment: Я как то встретил в примечание JDK, но больше ничего не говорилось. Так как уже начал писать, объясните мне пожалуйста. Я ничего не понял про подразрядные операции, там про биты про сдивги. Нужно ли это мне именно сейчас? Я просто не понимаю для чего эта функция (задачи, или как это назвать)

Comment: Вам, простите, лет сколько? Если Вы сейчас не знаете что такое поразрядные операции, булева алгебра, двоичная система счисления, значит пока что Вам это не нужно :).

Answer (score 3):

JDK + блокнот :-)

Comment: блокнот это сурово, хотя бы Vim или Emacs посоветовали чтоль :)

Answer (score 2):

JVM + eclipse =)

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans - для начала самое оно. Еще Eclipse, как уже было написано и IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Нужно попробовать все, это чисто субъективная вещь. Я предпочитаю IntelliJ IDEA CE.